# No Library cv2 on AzureML

Tags: azure, keras, pip, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to learn AzureML sdk and train my model on cloud.

I successfully train demo project located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-train-models-with-aml).

Now, that I want to train my own model, I get error :

```
UserError","message":"No module named 'cv2'","target":null,"details":[],"innerErro...
```

This means, that cv2 is not installed on AzureML and I use it in my train script,...

How to pip install library on AzureML or, how to "copy" virtual environment to my workspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to add `opencv-python-headless` as a pip installation 
like this:

```
TensorFlow(source_directory=script_folder,
                script_params=script_params,
                compute_target=compute_target,
                entry_script=train_script_name,
                pip_packages=['opencv-python-headless', 'scikit-image', 'mathematics', 'keras', 'scikit-learn'],
                use_gpu=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me, as I was getting the following error when trying to import cv2 in python:
`ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you are training on Azure ML managed compute?! If so, you need to specify all your required packages in a Conda dependencies file. See here for guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-set-up-training-targets#system-managed-environment

> Use a system-managed environment when you want Conda to manage the
>   Python environment and the script dependencies for you. A
>   system-managed environment is assumed by default and the most common
>   choice. It is useful on remote compute targets, especially when you
>   cannot configure that target.
>
> All you need to do is specify each package dependency using the
>   CondaDependency class Then Conda creates a file named
>   conda_dependencies.yml in the aml_config directory in your workspace
>   with your list of package dependencies and sets up your Python
>   environment when you submit your training experiment.

Alternativly, if you are using estimators and require only a few packages, you can also specify them directly:

```
estimator = SKLearn(source_directory=project_folder, 
                script_params=script_params,
                compute_target=compute_target,
                entry_script='train_iris.py'
                pip_packages=['joblib']
               )
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-train-scikit-learn#create-a-scikit-learn-estimator

Comment: Hi, thank you. I use SKLearn. I add pip_packages=['opencv'] and now I get the error : Collecting opencv (from -r /azureml-setup/condaenv.p5_1v_zd.requirements.txt (line 1))
[91m  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from -r /azureml-setup/condaenv.p5_1v_zd.requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)

Comment: looks like the package is called `opencv-python` https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: Ok, now it pass this but get error after :     File "train.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_62431a64abe69dd83df2462885045150/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: is your train.py running fine in your local env with python 3.6?

Comment: Yes it does,... the problem seems to be with import of cv2,.... although pip installation goes ok.